# Using Switch Case to Replace If Condition

Tags: switch-statement, powershell-2.0

I would like to understand more about switch statement and how to implement it. I have the following raw code to set the paging file. I would like to change the if and elseif condition after "Write-Host Windows 2008 edition detected" to switch case.

Is it possible to do that with Switch statement? I have tried different formula on that, but still couldn't find the perfect code.

Here is the code.

```
$OSbuild = [environment]::OSVersion.Version.Build ## Checking the OS version
$Drives = ".\Drives.txt"
$Cdrive = "C: Hard Drive"
$Ddrive = "D: Hard Drive"
$Pdrive = "P: Hard Drive"
$OthDrive1 = "[^DP]: Hard Drive"
$OthDrive2 = "[^CDP]: Hard Drive"


$Disk = Get-WmiObject win32_logicaldisk 

Foreach ($Drive in $Disk) 
    {
    Switch ($Drive.DriveType) 
        {
        1{$Disks = $Drive.DeviceID + " Unknown"; Break} 
        2{$Disks = $Drive.DeviceID + " Floppy or Removable Drive"; Break} 
        3{$Disks = $Drive.DeviceID + " Hard Drive"; Break} 
        4{$Disks = $Drive.DeviceID + " Network Drive"; Break} 
        5{$Disks = $Drive.DeviceID + " CD"; Break} 
        6{$Disks = $Drive.DeviceID + " RAM Disk"; Break} 
        }
    Write $Disks >> $Drives 
    }

if (Get-Content $Drives | ? {$_ -like $Pdrive})
    {
    Proces A
    }

elseif ($OSbuild -eq 6001 -or 7601)
    {
    Write-Host "Windows 2008 edition detected."
    $OSversion = "2008"

    if (Get-Content $Drives | ? {$_ -like $Ddrive}) ## Multiple drives found (with D) in the server
        {
        Process B
        }

    elseif (Get-Content $Drives | ? {$_ -match $OthDrive2}) ## Multiple drives found (without D) in the server
        {
        Process C
        }

    elseif (Get-Content $Drives | ? {$_ -like $Cdrive -notmatch $OthDrive1}) ## Only C drive found in the server
        {
        Process D
        }

    else
        {
        Write "Couldn't find the paging file rule for this server!"
        }
    }
```

Comment: FWIW you can replace the entire foreach bit with `Get-WmiObject win32_logicaldisk | ForEach { $_.DeviceID + ' ' + [IO.DriveType]$_.DriveType } | Out-File $Drives`

Comment: Your conditions are ill-suited for a switch statement, since it takes scalar objects (like in your first example) rather than arrays as its input

Comment: @wOxxOm, Thanks for your input. But the output given with that script is different. 

This is the output with your script
C: Fixed
D: Fixed
E: Fixed

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen, means I cannot use switch statement it's because the Get-Content command and pipe it to expression?

Comment: That is correctly understood

Comment: @MathiasR, okey got it. Thanks for your explaination.